# How to develop an c# wrapper(sdk) in uwp using pure 'c' dll's

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm new to uwp. I have dll's written in c language, i will write a wrapper in c# for these 'c' dll's in uwp. Now how can i bundle these DLL's (c and C# wrapper) into one file, such that other developers can use my file (reference it like sdk in their project) and develop their own applications. So how to develop an SDK in c# in uwp with c dll's.

Basically i want to develop an sdk for windows mobile 10 in c# with c dll's(where the functionality lies). Please help me...

Thanks.

Comment: You are lacking very basic knowledge with respect to UWP. You don't need any provisioning to support access to your UWP component from C#. Just implement your `IInspectable`-derived types, and expose the type factories. C++/CX probably provides the easiest route. Still way too broad a topic.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DllImport` and `extern` methods? See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern

Comment: Also, it would be better for you (and for future code maintenance) to translate your C dll's to C#

Comment: Thanks for the reply... here my doubt is can we package c dll's and c# wrapper dll's into single package (sdk), so that it can be referenced and develop UWP applications using this sdk.